# Render attribute content on condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to conditionally define the content of an HTML 5 data attribute:

```
<img @(String.IsNullOrEmpty(prd.Reference) 
  ? String.Format("data-title='{0}'", prd.Name) 
  : String.Format("data-title='{0}({1})'", prd.Name, prd.Reference)) />
```

When I run this code it is rendered as follows (when reference is not null):

```
<img data-title="'Product"/>
```

Sometimes even more strange result ... The Reference is missing.

Does anyone knows what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Html.Raw:

```
    <img @Html.Raw((String.IsNullOrEmpty(prd.Reference) 
  ? String.Format("data-title='{0}'", prd.Name) 
  : String.Format("data-title='{0}({1})'", prd.Name, prd.Reference)) />
```